# PHP, need help using cURL as allow_url_fopen is disabled

Tags: php, curl, feed, image-resizing

I need some help. I'm very new to cURL. I got a script working that would create a feed from a wordpress blog (with magpie XML parser). I also got an image resize script to resize the images for me. It works locally but because my web hosting has allow_url_fopen() disabled I've been told I need to use cURL but I can't get anything to work.

Here's the code BEFORE I tried to get cURL working:

```
<?php


$url = $_GET['imagesrc'];


// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Content type


// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($url);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
return(imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download image file to local machine and then use it in `imagecreatefromjpeg($filePointer);`. Code to download file is as follows.

```
/**
 * Initialize the cURL session
 */
 $ch = curl_init();

 /**
 * Set the URL of the page or file to download.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ‘your_URL’);

 /**
 * Create a new file
 */
 $fp = fopen(‘img.jpg’, ‘w’);

 /**
 * Ask cURL to write the contents to a file
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

 /**
 * Execute the cURL session
 */
 curl_exec ($ch);

 /**
 * Close cURL session and file
 */
 curl_close ($ch);
 fclose($fp);
```